# UILabel don't wrap even if I set `numberOfLines = 0`

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, unwrap

I have a custom `tableViewCell`. `questionContent` is a label, which I set:

```
numberOfLines = 0
lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

but it doesn't wrap.

This is the `questionContent`label:

```
let questionContent: UILabel = {

            let tempView = UILabel()
            tempView.numberOfLines = 0
            tempView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
            tempView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return tempView
        }()
```

in `layoutSubviews()` I set it's frame

```
//questionContent
            let questionContentX = avatorImageX
            let questionContentY = CGRectGetMaxY(avatorImage.frame) + answeModel!.marginTopBottomLeftOrRight
            let questionContentWidth = kScreenWidth - answeModel!.marginTopBottomLeftOrRight * 2
            let questionContentHeight = answeModel!.contentRealSize.height
            questionContent.frame = CGRectMake(questionContentX, questionContentY, questionContentWidth, questionContentHeight)
```

the first data `questionContent.text = "Ssddfghjj ssddfghjjkk sssssffhjjk sasdfgghjjjkkllljhhgggggffdddssssaaaasfghjkkllnnvcczzzeefggghjjkkkklllkjhggtrrrddssdfcvvvxxcbbb"` the `questionContent.frame` is `(8.0, 46.0, 304.0, 84.0)` but it doesn't wrap. here is the screenshot

[image]

Comment: maybe u miss the width constraint of the label? like from the right label to the right edge of the screen? or u forced the label height also will cause this to happen

Comment: I set the `frame`.  is this the problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting estimated row height of the cell?              `_tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;`  `_tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50;`

Comment: no, I don't set estimated row height.

Comment: please check "layoutSubviews" method has beed called or not.

Comment: I checked,  `layoutSubviews()` method has beed called

Comment: @AshutoshDave I add `rowHeight` and `estimatedRowHeight` but it doesn't work

Comment: @rose Are there any autolayout constraints?

Comment: no, I only set it's `frame` in `layouSubviews()`

Comment: @rose I tried it with autolayout constraints and it works and it's easy too. Try the method suggested by girish_pro below without using layoutsubview() method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

Add `sizeToFit` line and try.

```
let questionContent: UILabel = {

            let tempView = UILabel()
            tempView.numberOfLines = 0
            tempView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
            tempView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
            tempView.sizeToFit()
            tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            return tempView
        }()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is worked for me.

```
let questionContent: UILabel = {

        let tempView = UILabel()
        tempView.numberOfLines = 0
        tempView.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15)
        tempView.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
        tempView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        tempView.text = " This is two long text.This is two long text.This is two long text.This is two long text.This is two long text.This is two long text.This is two long text.";
        tempView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 10.0);
        tempView.sizeToFit()
        return tempView
        }()
```

No need to write into layoutsubview() method.

Answer (score 0):

I just fall to the same issue. I was adding the label to the cell like this:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    addSubview(messageText) // add to cell itself
}
```

Then after a whole lot of time, changed to:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.addSubview(messageText)
}
```

Just needed to add the label to the `contentView`